# sql query to bring results on 1st of any month when an event falls on any day of the month

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where query brings data when the evaluation_date is 90 days due...right now.
the new requirement is ...
The actual date of evaluation_date can fall on any day of the month but the report has to bring the record on the 1st of that particular month itself. For eg : If the evaluation_date due is 2017-07-08 0r 9 th, 10 th etc.. then the report still has to report evaluation_date due on 2017-07-01 .

the query has to look for next 3 months due and and bring all the data in that month.I ran query on apr 10  brings next 90 days data until jul 10. But i will need all days of july data...even over jul 10. how do i do it?

any inputs appreciated

Comment: use the day function to find the day of the date, then dateadd to add 1 - day, days to the date

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to truncate a date to the first of the month:

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0)
```

---

If you need to bring in all evaluations from the current month (e.g. April 1st even when run on April 10th)

```
select 
  ... 
  , evaluation_date = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0)
from t
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0) <= dateadd(month, 3, getdate())
  and dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0) >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

If you only need to bring in all evaluations from the current month as of the run date (e.g. April 10th when run on April 10th)

```
select 
  ... 
  , evaluation_date = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0)
from t
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0) <= dateadd(month, 3, getdate()) 
  and dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0) >= convert(date,getdate())
```

This piece from the above examples brings in all of July, e.g. July 30th even when run on April 10th:

```
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, evaluation_date), 0) <= dateadd(month, 3, getdate())
```